# Как по одному значению цвета в словаре определить цвета RGB?

Tags: python, pil

Ищу цвет определенного пикселя по моду RGB. На выводе имею два значения (цвет , кол-во пикселей). Так как RGB имеет 3 значения. Пример RGB(255,255,255) - Белый цвет.

Проблема в том что я не могу понять как по одному значению цвета в словаре 
определить цвета RGB.

```py
im = Image.open("путь к картинке в формате png").convert("RGB")
his = im.histogram()

values = {}

for i in range(256):
    values[i] = his[i]

for j, k in sorted(values.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:10]:
    print(j, k)
```

Вывод:

255 311822
250 111295
254 7339
253 5328
235 4362
237 3908
252 3892
251 3713
249 3140
234 3097

Comment: я так понял, что для получения палитры мы конвертируем изображение в convert("P") ???

Comment: А какая у вас изначальная задача стоит?

Comment: Отрисовать границы границы городов на карте

Comment: Возможно стоит такой вопрос и задать, типа "Как отрисовать на ///тип карты/// карте границы городов?" и картинку приложить, и попытки решения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по описанию (https://pythontic.com/image-processing/pillow/histogram и http://www.effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.histogram), гистограма в PIL работает не совсем так. Это не частоты отдельных цветов. Это частоты компонентов отдельных каналов.

Для RGB изображения (3 цветовых канала) она отдаст всего 768 элементов - 256 для красного канала, 256 для синего и 256 для зеленого.

```
# Get the color histogram of the image
histogram = image.histogram()

# Take only the Red counts
l1 = histogram[0:256]

# Take only the Blue counts
l2 = histogram[256:512]

# Take only the Green counts
l3 = histogram[512:768]
```

Таким образом имея значения гистограмы нельзя узнать конкретные цвета пикселей.